# Centrar tabla html

Tags: php, html

Buenas tengo estas tablas generadas en pdf mediante `php` en `html`, y me gustaría centrarlas, pero no lo consigo. Adjunto el código:

```
 $content .= '
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-12">             
          <h2>Jornada 1</h2>
          <h3>'.$user['Fecha_Inicio'].'</h3>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="5">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th bgcolor="grey" width="22%">LOCAL</th>
        <th bgcolor="grey" width="22%"></th>
        <th bgcolor="grey" width="22%">VISITANTE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>  
  ';
  $content .= '
<tr>
      <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E7'].'</td>
      <td width="22%" align="center">VS</td>
      <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E8'].'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E9'].'</td>
      <td width="22%" align="center">VS</td>
      <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E4'].'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E5'].'</td>
      <td width="22%" align="center">VS</td>
      <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E2'].'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E1'].'</td>
      <td width="22%" align="center">VS</td>
      <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E6'].'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E3'].'</td>
      <td width="22%" align="center">VS</td>
      <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E10'].'</td>
  </tr>
';
 $content .= '</table>';
```

Gracias,

Saludos

Comment: ¿Quieres que la tabla esté centrada en la pantalla o que su contenido esté centrado dentro de la tabla?

Comment: Que la tabla este centrada en la pantalla

Comment: Entonces sigue las indicaciones que ha dado Vera en su respuesta. Con un `margin='0 auto'` debería funcionar.

Answer (score 2):

Yo, donde pone `<div class="col-md-12">` añadiría una nueva clase, por ejemplo algo como esto:

```
<div class="col-md-12 tableCenter">
```

Y luego definiría la clase tableCenter con text-align='center' o, según si tienes o vas a poner más clases o elementos, con un margin='0 auto'

Answer (score 1):

Puedes centrar la tabla a su contenedor creando una clase, por ejemplo `.table-center` e indicar los margenes y ancho de la misma.

#### Demo:

```css
.table.table-center {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2>Jornada 1</h2>
    <h3>'.$user['Fecha_Inicio'].'</h3>
    <table class="table table-center">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th bgcolor="grey" width="22%">LOCAL</th>
          <th bgcolor="grey" width="22%"></th>
          <th bgcolor="grey" width="22%">VISITANTE</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E7'].'</td>
        <td width="22%" align="center">VS</td>
        <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E8'].'</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E9'].'</td>
        <td width="22%" align="center">VS</td>
        <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E4'].'</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E5'].'</td>
        <td width="22%" align="center">VS</td>
        <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E2'].'</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E1'].'</td>
        <td width="22%" align="center">VS</td>
        <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E6'].'</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E3'].'</td>
        <td width="22%" align="center">VS</td>
        <td width="22%">'.$user['Nombre_E10'].'</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```